# django ajax query returning error 10053 - An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: django, jquery

I am running a local django server and doing a simple ajax post request but I keep on getting this error. I have seen the related questions on this on SO which point to APPEND_SLASH but that isn't my problem here. 
I have a UserProfile which I am trying to save through an ajax query. The server actually executes the ajax view and I can see the prints from the view but it never reaches the jquery ajax success function.

I can run the ajax view perfectly from the homepage but not from this page which is **/edit_profile_details** page. Would really appreciate some help.

```
  <script>
    function js_save_profile(data) {
      alert("This is a test");
      $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'ajax_save_profile' %}",
        type:"POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() {
          added_html = "<div class='alert'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>Hello</button><strong>Warning!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good. </div>"
          $("#forms").append(added_html);
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
```

My ajax.py looks like this.

```
@csrf_exempt
def save_profile(request):
    user_id=1
    print
    print
    print "Save Profile Changes: "
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(id=user_id)
    print user_profile.user.username
    print "\n\n\n\n\n\n"
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({ 'user_name' : user_profile.user.username }), mimetype="application/javascript")
```

The urls.py looks like this.

```
url(r'edit_profile_details/', edit_profile_details, name='edit_profile_details'),
url(r'^ajax/save_profile/', save_profile, name='ajax_save_profile'),
```

And the output (including the error looks like this).

```
[16/Jun/2013 23:45:53] "GET /static/Highcharts-3.0.1/js/themes/gray.js HTTP/1.1"
 304 0


Save Profile Changes:
sarangis

[16/Jun/2013 23:45:59] "POST /ajax/save_profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 25
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 128, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 212, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 270, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 194, in send_preamble
    'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())
  File "c:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in yo
ur host machine
[16/Jun/2013 23:45:59] "POST /ajax/save_profile/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
-[16/Jun/2013 23:45:59] "GET /edit_profile_details/? HTTP/1.1" 200 7229
---------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 29750)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 593, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 150
, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 279, in close
    self.flush()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in yo
ur host machine
----------------------------------------
```

**[UPDATE]: ** I have also tried changing the urls.py ajax url to this.

```
url(r'^edit_profile_details/ajax/save_profile/', save_profile, name='ajax_save_profile'),
```

This didn't solve the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this answer is a bit late but try modifying your js script to capture the event then add event.preventDefault(); The issue is that otherwise the connection between client and server is closed when the view tries to return the response.